# I'm trying to create a windows forms app, where i can update my data by clicking on an element from the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code of that gridview:

```
int Key = 0;

private void DepList_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DepNameTb.Text = DepList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    if (DepNameTb.Text == "")
    {
        Key = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Key = Convert.ToInt32(DepList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'

[Once I click here the error shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V4aP.png)

By this I wanted the department name to show up on that textbox, edit it there and click the update button to update the data

Comment: `SelectedRows[0]` is throwing exception. as no row was selected.

Comment: Consider setting the DataGridView.DataSource to a BindingSource where the BindingSource DataSource might be a DataTable. Now subscribe to PositionChanged event of the [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), in the event check if the Current property of the BindingSource is not null followed by casting the Current property to a DataRow which you can then access properties of the current row. If you like I can post a generic code sample.

Answer (score 0):

It is better that you call 'CellClick' event instead of 'CellContentClick'.

> `DataGridView.CellContentClick` event occurs when the content within a
> cell is clicked.
>
> `DataGridView.CellClick` event occurs when any part of a cell is
> clicked.

Try below code to get selected cell value and key of its row:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int key = 0;
    var name = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
    if (name == "")
    {
        key = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        key = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[0].Value);
    }
}
```